# Asp.net Core Razor Pages serialization not working with CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, razor-pages, camelcasing

I'm using Asp.net Core Razor Pages and I'm returning json. I need the json to be in camel casing across the board, therefore I tried to set the resolver in **Startup.cs** like this

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
             options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
```

However this does not work, the razor page is still returning json in Pascal casing.  How do I correct the issue?  Thank you.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I'm using this JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `AddJsonOptions`, you are configuring an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` that is specific to ASP.NET Core MVC. When you use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, you're using a *different* instance of `JsonSerializerSettings`. In order to affect *that* instance, you can use [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm), like so:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

Unfortunately, changes you make to `DefaultSettings` do not apply to the instance that's configured via `AddJsonOptions` - You'll need to configure those separately. You can see how that is a separate instance that gets created by a `JsonSerializerSettingsProvider` in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.cs#L29), if you're interested.